# Is WebServiceContext injection into a static variable safe?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

Does it make a difference if I inject the web service context in a Java EE 6 web service into a static variable instead of a instance variable?

```
@Stateless
@Startup
@WebService(name = "/service")
public class ServiceBean {


@Resource
    private static WebServiceContext wsContext;
```

With JBoss 6, I can successfully access the context within a service method to get the message context, for example to get the remote IP address:

```
private String getRemoteIpAddress() {
        MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();
        HttpServletRequest req
                = (HttpServletRequest) mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
        return req.getRemoteAddr();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "safe"?

Comment: @TMichelsen safe in the sense that it makes no difference for the application (edited the question body)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with it being static?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos for initialization of `private static final` variables in a static initialzer, for example by reading values from the web.xml only once

Comment: I have a bad feeling about it - meaning I wouldn't do it. I cannot back it up from an official source though, so take it with a grain of salt. Also I bet there are other ways to read things from web.xml only once and still make them available to the application, without resorting to statics. CDI would be useful for this. Good luck anyway.